# Interact with 3D BIM models with collisions

Tags: android, scenekit, autodesk-forge, arcore

I'd like to build an app to interact with 3D BIM models, and I need to load files in .ifc (or .dae/.obj/.fbx/etc...) formats and move virtual camera like human walking on stairs, rooms. Need to pick elements like a door or a wall by tuching it and change it's color and get component details from my BIM model.

I found:

1. [AUTODESK Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/developers_guide/overview/) but I guess I cannot config it nativley as per my requirements
2. [ViroCore](https://virocore.viromedia.com/docs) but it seems poor and doesn't have support for .ifc/.dae only .obj and .fbx and I loose quality in conversion.
3. [AR Core](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/) - cannot use it without AR core support (limited devices has this feature)

Any advices are apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Need to pick elements like a door or a wall by tuching it and change it's color and get component details

Forge Viewer has just the thing for you - see [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.html#setThemingColor) and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/adding-custom-properties-property-panel), and [here's](https://jsbin.com/disopoq/edit?) a preview (iOS Safari) of the feature in question:

```
viewer.setThemingColor(4, new THREE.Vector4((1.0 / 255) * 219, (1.0 / 255) * 114, (1.0 / 255) * 255, 1))) // set color coding of a given component to rgb(219,114,255)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried Forge Viewer using their API, works like your example, but it uses so much GPU that my device just shows error page.

Comment: You should optimize your viewer settings or your model because such GPU usage is not normal

Comment: Check out memory settings [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v215) - should the high usage persist send the model over (via a sharing service like weTransfer/Dropbox/GDrive) to forge.help@autodesk.com so we can look into it